# Inflating a series of images to linearlayout in android app

Tags: android, android-imageview, layout-inflater, blackjack

I am working on a blackjack Android app and I am using this method to inflate card images. I use the values of the card to determine what image to load and the index to know what ImageView to add it to. I call this for each card in the players hand. The first card displays, but none after that show up. I checked the log and the image names and locations are correct for the second cards.

```
for(int i = 0; i < playerHand.getCardCount(); i++)
{
  addPlayerCardImage(playerHand.getCardByIndex(i), i);
}

private void addPlayerCardImage(Card pCard, int cardIndex)
{
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  cardImageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, playerhandlayout , false);

  String selectedImage = "card" + pCard.getValue() + pCard.getSuitAsCharacter();
  int CardImageID = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedImage, "drawable",getPackageName());
  Log.d("FLAG", "Card " + selectedImage);

  String cardLocation = "imageViewCard" + cardIndex;
  int cardLocationID = getResources().getIdentifier(cardLocation, "id",getPackageName());
  Log.d("FLAG", "Card location " + cardLocation);

  ImageView cardImage = (ImageView) cardImageView.findViewById(cardLocationID);

  cardImage.setImageResource(CardImageID);
  playerhandlayout.addView(cardImageView);
}
```

This is inflated layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCard0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCard1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCard2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCard3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCard4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cardback" />

</LinearLayout>
```

playerhandlayout xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/playerhandlayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The above code shows only one card.. where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Can you include the xml for `playerhandlayout` so that we can check it's nothing simple like the layout being horizontal when it should be vertical or similar?

Comment: Hmm, the way you set `cardLocationId` makes it seem like `cardlayout` has an `ImageView` for each card in the XML. But then why are you inflating it multiple times? Won't you end up with four card `ImageViews` for each card?

Comment: I assume the recently added XML is `R.layout.cardlayout`.  What does `playerhandlayout` look like in XML?

Comment: playerhandlayout is a horizontal linear layout within the main game layout

Comment: cogentapps was right, i tried following a different example that didn't work for my application. I made only one imageView in the cardslayout, took out reference to the playershandlayout in the inflate method, and indexed the addView method